Dynamical properties of cellular automata of small diameter
Let $f\colon\{0,1\}^k\to\{0,1\}$ be a function, $j$ an integer, and define the cellular automaton $F\colon\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ by $F(x)_i=f(x_{i+j},\dotsc,x_{i+j+k-1})$.
I wonder if cellular automata of diameter $k\leq 4$ (or even $k\leq 5$) have been classified into dynamical properties, that is, finding out how many (and maybe which ones) that are sensitive to initial conditions, topologically transitive, positively expansive, open etc.
Edit: More precisely, given the local rule $f$, are there algorithms to check whether the induced $F$ is, e.g., positively expansive or open?

https://hal.science/hal-01583896/ for list of non-permutive surjective rules with $k=6$.

Decidability of openness is just  automata theory. Positive expansivity is to my knowledge open. Topological transitivity is undecidable by Kari and Lukkarila.

To clarify the "to my knowledge", I think its decidability is one of the main open problems in the field.

I missed sensitivity, that's also undecidable, due to Lukkarila & Kari.

@VilleSalo thanks, by undecidable, do you mean the problem for general k? I mean, for the particular examples of non-permutive for k=4 or even 5, is it possible to determine whether they are sensitive to initial conditions, topologically transitive, positively expansive?

@VilleSalo also, you say openness is just automata theory, could you point me in a direction of reference?

No I don't know a reference, but it means constant degree (I think this is already in Hedlund) with a bound obviously coming from surjectivity. So in monadic second order logic over
integers you can state that for every configuration there's exactly $m$ preimages.

You can check if Kari's lecture notes discuss it. It's not research level by any means.

Alternatively, open iff biclosing. I think decidability of closing is explained in many places. (E.g. in our sequentialization paper, but it's not the "right" reference)

By undecidability I mean algorithmic, so general $k$ obviously. If you mean like ZFC, I think it's undecidable by present proofs much later than $k=5$. At 5 there are IIRC already a lot of surjective non-permutive CA, maybe at 4 they are manageable.

@VilleSalo thanks again, to check openness for a concretely defined CA, I guess one could search for pairs of elements with different sizes of their preimages to get non-openness; I just wonder if there is a better approach

To prove it, you can show biclosing. To prove it fails, you can find two eventually periodic points with different amounts of preimages.
